# Antilog of Shannon entropy (exponential entropy)

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, information-theory, entropy

In the source article at the bottom, the antilog of entropy is introduced as the exponential of Shannon entropy:

$$ H(N) = -\sum_N w_i \ln w_i $$

$$ e^{H(N)} = \prod_N w_i ^{w_i} $$

1. Could someone show the steps in between $e^{H(N)}$ and how to get to $\prod_N w_i ^{w_i} $?
2. and can the last measure also be applied to point-wise probabilities of a random variable like how Shannon entropy normally is used for, i.e. $p(x)$ instead of $w_i$ so that, for random variable $X$,

$$e^{H(X)} = \prod_N p(x) ^{p(x)}?$$

> Straathof, S. M. (2007). Shannon's entropy as an index of product variety. Economics Letters, 94(2), 297-303.

Comment: By the laws of indices/logarithms, $$\exp H(N)=  \exp\Big(-\sum_{N} w_i\log w_i\Big) = \prod_{N} \exp(-w_i\log w_i) = \prod_{N} \exp(\log(w_i^{-w_i})) = \prod_N {w_i}^{-w_i},$$ since $\exp$ and $\log$ are inverses of each other.

Comment: thanks, could you change the comment to an answer

Comment: @deverlarist I did it as a comment cause I didn't really answer your second point.

Answer (score 2):

By the laws of indices/logarithms, $$\exp H(N)=  \exp\Big(-\sum_{N} w_i\log w_i\Big) = \prod_{N} \exp(-w_i\log w_i) = \prod_{N} \exp(\log(w_i^{-w_i})) = \prod_N {w_i}^{-w_i},$$ since $\exp$ and $\log$ are inverses of each other.

Comment: the question was edited with a second question if you're up for it

Comment: can the laws of indices/logarithms also be used to produce the same result if Shannon entropy were replaced with **differential entropy**: $$h(X) = \int f(x) \log f(x) dx ?$$

Comment: @develarist Not easily, no. There is no equivalent to $\exp\big(\sum{}\cdot{}\big) = \prod\exp({}\cdot{})$ for integrals.