# Is antilog the same as exponential function?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation

An [article](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902393/antilog-of-shannon-entropy-exponential-entropy) has implied that **antilog** and **exponentiation** $e$ just mean the same thing. All I know about antilog though is that it means an inverse logarithm. I don't know if it has a mathematical symbol or anything else, and want to check whether antilog does in fact mean $e$, or if some simple examples can be given that might help understand the earlier link, or in what situations an antilog is possible or not, given that the function in the link *contains* a logarithm but is not *entirely* a logarithmic function.

Comment: Inverse of logarithm function $\log_b x$ is exponential $b^x$

Answer (score 2):

Yes the natural log of $e^{x}$ is $x$ and $e^{\ln{x}}=x$ so it is reasonable to say that taking the exponential (to base $e$) is the same as the antilog (to base $e$). The inverse of log to base $10$ (for example) is to raise $10$ to the power of $x$.